# C++ modules to speed up template functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-modules

In general, using function templates makes the compilation significantly longer.

A friend suggested that I check the modules (C++20) for optimization.

I don't think it will affect compilation speed at all.

I have no idea how to test this, so I'm asking here.

Will the following code somehow magically optimize the build process?

The definition will still have to be created and compiled, so it won't make any difference?

math.ixx:

```
module; 
#include <typeinfo>

export module math;
import <iostream>;

export 
template<typename T>
T square(T x) {
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
  return x * x;
}
```

main.cpp

```
import math;

void main() {
  square(int());
  square(double());
}
```

Comment: "In general ..." ? Does it, really?

Comment: you can test this by measuring the time it takes to compile the code. I would expect that for any effect to be significant you need to generate some code where many function templates are defined and instantiated. First of all you need some alternative to compare against.

Comment: It won't be fast if you recompile everything every time. Just recompile exactly what's needed w.r.t. the changes you've made since last time you compiled. You could use precompiled headers too to make that part faster.

Comment: After some experiments with C++20 modules, I now see them as an *enhanced alternative to precompiled headers*. They can indeed increase compilation speed, but not that much compared to precompiled headers. The **parse** time can be indeed drastically decreased, but not the time for template **instantiation**.

Comment: @prapin given what I've been reading on compiler dev blogs... that's exactly how they are implemented for the most part. So that's pretty much spot on target. They still encourage their use because it means less issues when a module is changed, only modules importing that module have to be recompiled.

Comment: @prapin Precompiled headers (PCR) take up a lot of space, and I have found that they can significantly slow down compilation times if they get big enough - which usually happens since the "official" advice is to use a single PCR for an entire project.
Also, modules are _standardized_ (even though the BMI implementation isn't).
If compilers weren't so buggy I would use modules wherever I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code example is too trivial for modules to be of any real use. One file which includes a second file, and nothing includes anything else is not a compilation problem. It's like trying to benchmark how fast adding two integer literals is and then making a statement about the quality of C++'s addition operator.

From a performance perspective, modules solves the following problem: they keep the cost of recompiling a single file from being equal to the cost of recompiling every file that first file includes regardless of whether the included files changed.

If you `#include <vector>` in a simple program, your source file now contains *thousands* of lines of code. If you change that source file, the compiler will have to recompile thousands of lines of code which *did not change*. If you have 1000 files that each include `<vector>`, you now have 1000 *identical copies* of `<vector>` which the compiler *must* compile every time you compile all of those files.

This is the sort of thing that modules prevent. If you import a module for a library, you changing your source file will not necessitate recompiling those included headers. If you import dozens of modules across hundreds or thousands of files, this adds up pretty quickly.

Pre-modules, making a small change to a widely included header prompts a full recompilation of your entire project. In a fully-modularized codebase, there will be a lot of files that get recompiled. But what *doesn't* happen is that you recompile stuff that didn't rely on the change. You may have changed a widely used header, but you didn't change the C++ standard library. So if you included it via modules, then `<vector>` and such won't get recompiled.

This is where modules saves performance.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage of modules wrt. templates is that we may place templated code inside a *source file*, and compile that source file even though the compiler has no idea which *template instantiations* any consuming translation units will define.

This is possible because a compilation will provide two outputs: An object file and a BMI (binary module interface). The BMI is an abstract syntax tree serialized, and this can be used to generate template instantiations without re-compiling the source.

Pre-modules the only solution was to place templates inside header files, and thus we have entire libraries like `glm` where everything is a header file. This yields a lot of redundant compiler work (as Nicol Bolas exemplified with including `std::vector`).

The main cause of speedup, thus, is the avoidance of redundant header file parsing. Your example is a bit too small to be able to see any difference, but given enough header files and enough translations units which include those header files, we will end up with compiling the same header files multiple times (wasteful).